Docker-compose healthcheck requires "sh -c"
I have a docker-compose.yml with the following service:
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=cct1
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=cct1
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mysql-password
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mysql-password
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          # "sh",
          # "-c",
          "mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u $$MYSQL_USER --password=$$(cat /run/secrets/mysql-password)"
        ]
      start_period: 5s
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 6
    secrets:
      - mysql-password

secrets:
  mysql-password:
    file: ./mysql_pwd.secret

When I run docker stack deploy stack-name, the db service fails (Received SHUTDOWN from user root) and the reason is in the healthcheck. I have already found a working solution, but I am missing the logic: it seems that the mysqladmin ping ... command must be run inside a shell using sh -c:
[
  "CMD-SHELL",
  "sh",
  "-c",
  "mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u $$MYSQL_USER --password=$$(cat /run/secrets/mysql-password)"
]

And it works.

What I have tried
The documentation is pretty clear on what CMD-SHELL does:

Using CMD-SHELL runs the command configured as a string using the container's default shell (/bin/sh for Linux)

So why do I need an additional shell? Several other alternatives make the deployment fail, for example this one:
[
  "CMD",
  "sh",
  "-c",
  "mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u $$MYSQL_USER --password=$$(cat /run/secrets/mysql-password)"
]

Why? The second shell seems mandatory, but I cannot understand the reason. I have also inspected the MySQL Docker image but the SHELL is not overwritten.

Interesting. Instead of mysqladmin, I tried running env >> /proc/1/fd/1 as the healtcheck command to dump the environment variables to the container log. It works with CMD but not with CMD-SHELL. I can see the environment variables with CMD but not with CMD-SHELL. So there's a difference in how environment variables are handled, but I don't know why or how.

Thanks for investigating this! I expected that it would have worked with CMD-SHELL but not with CMD, not the opposite...

Yes, I would have expected that as well. It's weird. Maybe you can direct the output of your mysqladmin command to /proc/1/fd/1 to see if you get an error message.

I think that you can simplify this a bit. You probably don't need to specify credentials if you are just pinging the database.
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=cct1
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=cct1
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping" ]
      start_period: 5s
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 6

That uses a hard-coded password rather than the secret. But you should be able to docker-compose up and then verify that the container is marked as healthy.
Alternatively you could specify the health check like this:
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "mysqladmin ping" ]
      start_period: 5s
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 6

The difference (as I understand it!) is that CMD-SHELL will run the command in a shell, while CMD will run the command without a shell. The latter has less overhead, which might be significant if you are running the health check frequently.

Thanks for the suggestion but you are missing the point of the question. The difference (as I understand it!) is that CMD-SHELL will run the command in a shell, while CMD will run the command without a shell. This is what the documentation says but it is apparently not enough to explain the situation I have described. Please read again the question

It's not clear from the question what you are wanting explained. The difference between the two is that one runs a shell and the other doesn't. Please let me know what else is unclear.
